# Work on a pandas dataframe by index and categorical data

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe like the following:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({ 0: (188, 750, 1330, 1385, 188, 750, 1330, 1385),
                    4: (51.12, 51.45, 74.49, 29.21, 39.98, 3.98, 14.46, 16.51),
                    6: pd.Categorical(['R', 'R', 'R', 'R', 'F', 'F', 'F', 'F']) })
df = df.set_index([0])

df
          4  6
0             
188   51.12  R
750   51.45  R
1330  74.49  R
1385  29.21  R
188   39.98  F
750    3.98  F
1330  14.46  F
1385  16.51  F
```

How can I subtract the values in `F` from those in `R` for each of the indices?
For example, in this case the output would look like this:

```
      result
0           
188    11.14
750    47.47
1330   60.03
1385   12.70
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a boolean mask to filter the 2 slices of your df, and then just subtract, the subtraction will align on the indices:

```
In[13]:
df.loc[df[6] == 'R',4] - df.loc[df[6] == 'F',4]

Out[13]: 
0
188     11.14
750     47.47
1330    60.03
1385    12.70
Name: 4, dtype: float64
```